# how do i format my hard drive to ntfs from ext4

Tags: uninstall, ntfs, ext4, format

I have a usb with my windows ISO loaded and ready. Problem is there is no ntfs partition on my hard drive for windows to load onto. I don't want to complicate things by running 2 operating systems. I’d like to go back to windows. I like Ubuntu more but I have no clue what I’m doing. I’m not a programmer.

I’ve tried booting from my usb with windows 7 loaded on as well as a CD with vista ultimate. Neither gave me an option to repair my drive. Both have the option to delete partition, and the CD gave me the option to format partition. The formatting failed and I’m afraid to delete the partition because I don't know what to do if I delete Ubuntu and the drive remains in ext4 format.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that this is not the right place to ask this question. This is Ubuntu Forum and not Windows Forum and this question should be placed in Windows Forum if there is any.

Another piece of valuable information is Ubuntu is not for developers. It is for everyone. My dad who is 65 uses this and he is comfortable with Ubuntu than Windows. I still recommend you should continue to use Ubuntu and not to switch back to Windows.

To answer your question, if you have a Ubuntu live CD or USB, you should boot it with that, run gparted from there, then delete the partitions. Then you can create NTFS partitions from there. Once you restart, windows should able to read the partitions.

NOTE: If Windows bootable USB still do not recognize your hdd, then you will left with no OS on the system. You have been warned.

Comment: if its for everyone then i'm missing something. the community offers a lot of help but i read stuff and its like its in chinese. im gonna keep trying to learn it but for the moment i need to be able to install my new printer like my life depends on it.
anywho, yes, the no os is the part i'm worried about. if that were to happen, could i run ubuntu from my live cd?

Comment: If you want to add Printer, there is two ways of doing it. you can type http://localhost:631/ and you can add printer from there. If this doesn't work, then you can go into the system settings from Dash and then look for Printers and you can add them from there